# Rails: Ransack doesn't search associated models properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I followed the very useful Ransack [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast) but it doesn't work correctly on nested attributes.

I have a student model with a nested model, exams. Exams contain a subject, grade, and type. I can search for a student by the attributes of the student class, or by the attributes of the exams class.

So, if I search for all exams of History, it will return all students who have a History exam in their record. Which is good.

But suppose I search by students who took both a History exam and an English exam. It always returns zero students, even though many students took both.

It will only return true if I search across a single exam -- that is, a history exam with a score of 80. I can't search for two different exams at the same time, even though there are many students who have both exams on in their record.

I followed the code exactly from the Railscast. Why doesn't this work the way it should?

Comment: Probably because the railscast is from 2012.  Check ransack's documentation, it might have changed the api since then

Comment: I looked at the API, but it seems to be doing everything correctly. There's no syntax errors or anything like that, it just seems like there's an internal join that isn't being done correctly.

Comment: Please show the code you have actually written!